# UOW's: Relating UOW's listed in MSDTC to SQL Server info

Tags: sql-server, msdtc, distributed-transactions

We have some active transactions showing up in MSDTC that have been there for a very long time and don't go away. They're not orphaned or in-doubt, just normal-looking active transactions.

We're trying to figure out what they are and why they're there.

To that end, I'm trying to find a way to map one of these active transactions that are being presented in MSDTC Transaction List (Component Services -> My Computer -> Distributed Transaction Coordinator -> Transaction List) to any information at all in MS SQL Server.

Obviously, all I have to work with is a UOW ID.

After several hours of research, I can't find anything outside of sys.dm_tran_locks that would have this info.  The problem I'm having with sys.dm_tran_locks is that my transactions do not show up, presumably because they don't currently hold any locks.

Other important info:
SQL Server 2005. (Yes, 2005 :(  )
Again, nothing is "orphaned" or "in doubt". The transactions just show as active, but they stay there forever.
There is no clustering or anything else exotic. It's all very plain-vanilla SQL Server 2005 standard edition.

EDIT: I should also note that I tried:

```
* SP_WhoIsActive (both with default settings and with more info gathering turned on)
* sys.dm_tran_locks
* sys.dm_exec_sessions
* sys.dm_exec_requests.  
* sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
* sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
* sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
```

I'm beginning to think you just can't get there from here ;-)
Again, I want to associated a UOW in MSDTC to a UOW in SQL Server where, apparently, the distributed transaction is still active but holding no locks.

As requested, here is a screenshot of MSDTC:
[image: MSDTC Screen Shot]

Comment: Sp_whoisactive will help you.session ID column in sys.dm_tran_locks, sys.dm_exec_sessions, or sys.dm_exec_requests dynamic management views.

Comment: Thanks :-).  I should have noted in the original post that I tried Sp_whoisactive with default settings and did not get the UOW ID. I suppose I will go back and tweak the settings and try again. sys.dm_tran_locks showed nothing, but I  assumed it was because the transaction was not holding locks. I'll look into exec_sessions and exec_requests.

Comment: one more thing to check `req_transactionUOW` column `from master..syslockinfo` to see if you find useful.

Comment: Thanks again, Kin. I think that syslockinfo is pretty much the same as sys.dm_tran_locks.  Looks like if  I don't have a lock, I just can't get it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are telling - `some active transactions showing up in MSDTC that have been there for a very long time and don't go away. They're not orphaned or in-doubt, just normal-looking active transactions`.

Comment: Kin - I have added the screenshot. NOTE: There are no "in-doubt" transactions. They all show as active. I can get that for you as well if it helps. Really appreciate the help! :-)

Comment: BTW, Kin - don't work too hard on it.  I've pretty much concluded that it's impossible.  Just thought someone might have a wiz-bang tool or method for getting this.  Realistically, if SQL Server doesn't store it, it's just not there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the correlation you're looking for in the `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions` DMV.
The column is `transaction_uow`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174302.aspx

Comment: I'll check that out!